# Is there any way to split the root and the other paths in apache2?

Tags: apache

I am not sure what the correct terminology is, so I'm just going to give an example.

I want to host my website in my root, using git so i can easily pull new versions of my portfolio as I update it. And then I also just want to have miscellaneous sub-paths that I just have there either for fun, or just something else entirely.

So I want to structure to be

```
html
│
└──── actualroot
│
└──── otherstuff
```

and then I want the user to be able to access actual root by just going to the domain name `www.example.com` and then access the folder `otherstuff` by going to `www.example.com/otherstuff`

Is something like this possible? Maybe by redirecting if it doesn't find the path? Or should I just use a subdomain for all miscellaneous sites?

Comment: Look at the `Alias` directive in apache2. (Writing an actually useful answer will probably take me longer than it takes you to solve it by looking it up!)

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure this is possible.

However, it depends on your overall configuration. For a lot of hosters, it is a common pattern, to use the first-level-folder as subdomain-name.

I.e. in your example, you would have:

http://actualroot.mydomain.tld and 
   http://otherstuff.mydomain.tld

(so, it's easy to call the folder of your primary website "www")

---

Beside that, you can always use some simple `htaccess`-rules to rewrite any virtual-path to the actual physical path.

For instance (simplified, not complete, but should give you an idea):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^www\.mydomain\.tld/otherstuff/(.*)$ ./html/otherstuff/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^www\.mydomain\.tld/(.*)$ ./html/actualroot/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The user would enter `http://www.mydomain.tld` and see the content, as if he would have accessed `http://mydomain.tld/actualroot/`

(`http://www.mydomain.tld/otherstuff/` would show the content of `http://mydomain.tld/otherstuff/`)

Comment: Please note that the processing order (along with `[L]` is important!) - You can save a lot of work, if you process "longer" paths first, and let every shorter path be processed by the "next" rule (if the prior rule doesn't apply)

Comment: "Shorter" in Terms of "Folder-Count", delimited by `/`, not actual "characters": `http://mydomain.tld/aFreakingLongFolderName/` is to be considered shorter than `http://mydomain.tld/a/b/`

Comment: Took me some playing around, but I got it working using the RewriteEngine.